# What are commands to find shell keywords, built in functions and user defined functions?

Tags: shell, alias, command, function

I was discussing with my friend on how the commands are parsed in the shell, and he told me that bash searches the command in following order

1. List of aliases
2. List of shell keywords
3. List of user defined functions
4. List of shell built in functions
5. List of directories specified in the PATH variable , from left to right.

I know aliases can be found by issuing the `alias` command. PATH variable contents can be found using `echo $PATH` command.

Can you please tell me which commands do I need to use ?

1. To list all shell keywords
2. To list all user defined functions
3. To list of shell built in functions

Comment: It doesn't answer the "list all" part, but should be noted that for any *given* command you can use `type somecmd` or `type -a somecmd` to see which of the above categories it fits into.

Comment: Near-duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94775/135943  (I've linked in both directions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash:

1. `man bash | grep -10 RESERVED` lists reserved words:

   > ! case coproc do done elif else esac fi for function if in select then until while { }  time [[ ]]
2. `declare -F` and `typeset -F` shows function names without their contents.
3. `enable` lists builtin shell *commands* (I don't think these are *functions* as such).So does `man builtins`

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `compgen` in `bash`:

- `compgen -k` lists keywords
- `compgen -b` or `enable` lists builtins
- `compgen -A function` or `declare -F` lists functions
- `compgen -a` or `alias` lists aliases
- `compgen -c` lists commands
- `compgen -v` lists variables
- `compgen -e` or `export` lists exported variables

Answer (score 3):

With zsh:

```
PATH= type -m '*'
```

Will tell you all 3.

In bash, to list the keywords, you can do:

```
complete -A keyword :
```

and then type `: <Tab><Tab>`

For builtins, replace `keyword` with `builtin` above and for functions, I'll let you guess.

Comment: In zsh, the list of aliases, functions and builtins is also available as array keys: `print -l ${(ko)aliases}`, etc.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas : Thanks. But when I ran commands `complte -A keyword : <tab> <tab> ` and `complte -A builtin : <tab> <tab> ` , both times it prompted my "Display all 2154 possibilities? (y or n)

Comment: @CppLearner, that's not what I said. Enter the "complete" command, which redefines the completion for the ":" command, and then type :, space, tab and tab.

Comment: In bash: just typing `complete -A keyword` is enough. Don't know the exact version which added this capacity.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for the 2nd question in case of `bash` or `zsh`: `declare -f`.

Answer (score 0):

In bash

- keywords (reserved words):

  ```
  compgen -A keyword       # or:  compgen -k
  ```
- functions (defined at the point of execution):

  ```
  compgen -A function      # Only names.
  declare -F               # Only names but prefixed with `declare -f`.
  ```

  declare -f               # Full function definition.
- builtins

  ```
  compgen -A builtin       # Only names.
  enable                   # Names prefixed with `enable `
  man builtins             # Only if the correct man package is installed.
  ```

There are some other keywords for `compgen` as well: alias, commands, variables, export, etc.

A list of possible `compgen` `-A` options may be found by *completing*:

```
 compgen -A                  # and press Tab (Maybe twice vary by configuration).
```