# List all commands that a shell knows

Tags: shell, command

What can I type at my shell (which happens to be `bash`) that will list all the commands that are recognized?

Also, does this differ by shell? Or do all shells just have a "directory" of commands they recognize?

Secondly, different question, but how can I override any of those? In other words how can I write my own `view` command to replace the one existing on my Ubuntu system, which appears to just load `vim`.

Comment: Please don't combine questions. Post each one as a separate question.

Comment: Near-duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63073/135943  (I've linked in both directions.)

Answer (score 98):

You can use `compgen`

```
compgen -c # will list all the commands you could run.
```

FYI:

```
compgen -a # will list all the aliases you could run.
compgen -b # will list all the built-ins you could run.
compgen -k # will list all the keywords you could run.
compgen -A function # will list all the functions you could run.
compgen -A function -abck # will list all the above in one go.
```

Comment: Note that `compgen -c` will include things like `{` or `while` that are not strictly speaking commands.

Comment: +10 @rahul-patil has given a solid answer, and explained each step along the way.

Comment: You might want to add that `compgen` *only* works for bash. It does not work for any other shell I know; be they `sh`-compatible (e.g. `ash`, `dash`, `busybox sh`, `ksh`, `mksh`) or not (e.g. `csh`, `tcsh`, `zsh`, `fish`, ...).

Answer (score 24):

A shell knows four kinds of commands.

- Aliases: these are nicknames for a command with some options. They are defined in the shell's initialization file (`~/.bashrc` for bash).
- Functions: they are snippets of shell code given a name. Like aliases, they are defined in the shell's initialization file.
- Builtins: the shell comes with a small number of built-in commands. Most builtins manipulate the shell state (`cd` changes the current directory, `set` changes options and positional parameters, `export` changes the environment, …). Most shell offer largely the same builtins but each shell has a few extensions to the basic set.
- External commands: they are independent of the shell. Like other programs, the shell executes external programs by looking them up in the [executable search path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#Unix_and_Unix-like). The `PATH` environment variable contains a colon-separated list of directories to search for programs.

In case there are commands of several types by the same name, the first match in the order above is executed¹.

You can see what type of command a name corresponds to by running `type some_name`.

You can list aliases by running the `alias` built-in with no argument. There is no way to list functions or builtins that works in all shells. You can find a list of builtins in the shell's documentation.

In bash, the `set` builtin lists functions with their definitions as well as variables. In bash, ksh or zsh, `typeset -f` lists functions with their definitions. In bash, you can list all command names of any type with `compgen -c`. You can use `compgen -A alias`, `compgen -A builtin` `compgen -A function` to list commands of a specific type. You can pass an additional string to `compgen` to list only commands that start with that prefix.

In zsh, you can list the currently available commands of a given type with `echo ${(k)aliases}`, `echo ${(k)functions}`, `echo ${(k)builtins}` and `echo ${(k)commands}` (that last one lists external commands only).

The following shell-agnostic snippet lists all available external programs:

```
case "$PATH" in
  (*[!:]:) PATH="$PATH:" ;;
esac

set -f; IFS=:
for dir in $PATH; do
  set +f
  [ -z "$dir" ] && dir="."
  for file in "$dir"/*; do
    if [ -x "$file" ] && ! [ -d "$file" ]; then
      printf '%s = %s\n' "${file##*/}" "$file"
    fi
  done
done
```

There is an edge case in Bash: hashed commands.

[Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) says:

> A full search of the directories in $PATH is performed only if the command is not found in the hash table

Try:

```
set -h
mkdir ~/dir-for-wat-command
echo 'echo WAT!' >~/dir-for-wat-command/wat
chmod +x ~/dir-for-wat-command/wat
hash -p ~/dir-for-wat-command/wat wat
wat
```

The `PATH` environment variable doesn't contain `~/dir-for-wat-command`, `compgen -c` doesn't show `wat`, but you can run `wat`.

If you want to shadow an existing command, [define an alias or a function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4023/bash-functions-vs-scripts/4024#4024).

¹  <sub>Exception: a few builtins (called [special builtins](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/sbi.html)) cannot be shadowed by a function — bash and zsh don't comply with POSIX on that point in their default mode though.</sub>

Comment: Another edge case is for values of `$PATH` like `/bin:/usr/bin:` (trailing `:`), where it would fail to list the executable files in the  current directory.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
(   # usage of a sub processus: the modificaion of PATH variable is local in ( )
    PATH+=:EOF # little hack to list last PATH dir
    printf '%s\n' ${PATH//:/\/* }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The list of commands consists of two sets:

1. The commands built-in to the shell
2. The commands in your `PATH`

You can't change built-ins, but you can keep the shell from using a built-in by specifying the full pathname like `/bin/echo`.

As for the commands in your `PATH`, you *can* change that.  `PATH` is a colon-separated list of directories to look for commands in.  The first matching file found "wins".

```
export PATH=~/bin:${PATH}
```

(This syntax does not work for `csh`-derived shells, but all others that I know about).

That exports `PATH` with `~/bin` as the first entry followed by the rest of the existing `PATH` entries.  So now your shell will check `directory called`bin`in your home directory for a command *first* before checking the standard`PATH` the system set up.  You could easily make it check the new directory last by instead using:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/bin
```

To make the `PATH` persist for future logins, add it to a `.profile` or other shell rc file.

Answer (score 1):

If you press tab key twice and then y, you will get the list of all available command in your current shell.
For the second question I think you should use alias: [shell alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29).

Comment: regarding alias, is that a fool-proof way of overriding and un-overriding (by "unaliasing") a command when it is called anywhere on the system (for example from a shell script)?

Comment: What shell do you use? I can't get the double tab to list all commands on my bash.

Comment: I use bash on Ubuntu 13.04. There is also a command called compgen which can be used to get the list of all available commands on the bash.

Comment: @terdon Do you have bash completion installed?

Comment: Yes I do, but this does not work. Are you sure you are using bash? I tried with different users and also with `--norc` and it never works for me. Double tab does nothing unless I have started typing something. It might be a `shopt` option or something. Why don't you add an explanation of how to use `compgen` for this to your answer?

Comment: Someone else just did! :P

Comment: @terdon Almost all systems I use double-tapping TAB just works.  Are you really using `bash`, or are you using `/bin/sh`?  Since some systems (Debian, Ubuntu) default to `dash` for `/bin/sh`, you might be using `dash`.  And with my testing just now, `dash` does *not* do the double-tap TAB listing.

Comment: @kurtm nope, I'm on bash. Even tried with a `bash --norc` and with a new user with default settings and double tab does nothing unless I have started typing something. Also tried different terminals. Could you both have set an option somewhere that activates this? Can you confirm that double tab expands to all commands even without having typed anything, just an empty prompt?

Comment: @terdon What is your bash version?

Comment: @terdon I only tried with an empty prompt.  And I don't have a .bashrc or any bash-specific options in rc files.

Comment: 4.2.45(1) but I must have some weird setting somewhere I guess. It does not work on my laptop (LMDE, basically debian) but does on a SuSe server and on an Ubuntu VM I just tried it in. I'll have to look around and see what that might be. @kurtm

Comment: set show-all-if-ambiguous off

Comment: Run the above command and then try double tab again.

Answer (score 1):

In the `bash` shell, for the list of aliases, reserved words, functions and external commands in directories of `$PATH` (assuming none of them contain newline characters) sorted alphabetically:

```
compgen -ac | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gilles_Quenot's solution without paths, the pure commands:

```
printf '%s\n' ${PATH//:/\/* } | xargs -n 1 basename
```

(@Gilles_Quenot sorry, no reputation to comment)
There are more than 3600 commands ( printf '%s\n' ${PATH//://* } | wc ), so a file could be better:

```
printf '%s\n' ${PATH//:/\/* } | xargs -n 1 basename > commands.txt
```