# Suppress warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E

Tags: linux, grep, autocomplete

When I run `egrep`, it shows `warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E`

But I'm using it as part of my shell autocomplete script that I often use, and I don't want to rewrite them.

I'm looking for way to suppress those warnings, since my autocomplete become 'ugly', e.g.: when typing `mycmd myargum<TAB>`, I'm expecting autocomplete to make it `mycmd myargument`, but instead it writes:

```
mycmd myargum<TAB>grep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
grep: warning: egrep is obsolescent; using grep -E
ent
```

Currently I tried doing this:

```
mv /usr/bin/egrep /usr/bin/egrep.backup
echo 'grep -E $@' > /usr/bin/egrep
chmod a+x /usr/bin/egrep
```

It works by changing the grep binary to a script that calls 'grep -E' instead.

Additional info:

```
$ egrep.backup --version
egrep.backup: warning: egrep.backup is obsolescent; using grep -E
grep (GNU grep) 3.8
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others; see
<https://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

The question is:

- Is this method okay? Will it have unintended consequences?

  - Maybe it will make egrep.backup binary still undeleted if grep package is uninstalled/purged, but this should be non issue as I never planned to do that
- Is there any better way to suppress this warning message?

Comment: after a quick search, I realized that I can just make `alias egrep="grep -E"` in .bashrc since alias is prioritized over $PATH from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132628/477417

Comment: or, better yet, you could modify your scripts that use the obsolete `egrep` so that they use `grep -E` instead.   `egrep` has been deprecated for decades now, that's more than enough time to stop using it.

Comment: Use `echo 'grep -E "$@"' > /usr/bin/egrep`, ie double quote the `$@`

Comment: What will you do when `egrep` is completely removed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In GNU `grep`, `egrep` and `fgrep` are shell scripts anyway; starting with 3.8, these are where the obsolescence warning is produced:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cmd=${0##*/}
echo "$cmd: warning: $cmd is obsolescent; using grep -E" >&2
exec grep -E "$@"
```

Replacing them with your own version is fine; the previous version was

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec grep -E "$@"
```

(with an obvious variant for `fgrep`).

The only aspect to watch out for is that your packaging system still “owns” the `egrep` and `fgrep` binaries, so you’ll lose your changes whenever the package is upgraded. To avoid that, you can tell the packaging system that it no longer owns the files; in Debian derivatives, run

```
sudo dpkg-divert --divert /usr/bin/egrep.original --rename /usr/bin/egrep
sudo dpkg-divert --divert /usr/bin/fgrep.original --rename /usr/bin/fgrep
```

This will cause the packaging system to always rename the packaged file to `?grep.original`.

(Curious readers may want to [read the bug report which led to these warnings](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=49996), and [a few bug reports](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=57604) filed [as a result](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=58502).)

Comment: Strange that they would use a bash shebang when there's nothing bash-specific in there. That adds an unnecessary dependency to that shell. That means however that  one could call egrep as: `env 'BASH_FUNC_echo%%=() { :; }' egrep` to remove that warning. You could make your replacement script `#! /bin/bash -` / `exec -a "$0" grep -E "$@"` for it to mention `egrep` in its error messages.