# script doesn't show all the executable files in $PATH

Tags: bash, shell-script

I wanted to write a script on my Ubuntu to show all the executable files in all of the directories in the `$PATH` variable. Here is my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
IFS=:
for dir in $PATH;do
        echo $dir:
        for files in $dir/*;do
                b=$(basename $files)
                [ -x "$b" ] && echo $"    $b" 
        done
done
```

but the output is

```
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:
/snap/bin:
/home/sudin/programming/shell:
      brightness
      for
      ifthen
      loop
      mat2
      myfind
      searchex
```

Why aren't the executable files of other directories listed?

Answer (score 4):

With

```
[ -x "$b" ]
```

you’re testing if the file with the name stored in `$b`, *without* a path, is executable; so the script will only find entries on the `PATH` which happen to match an executable in the current directory.

Testing the full path will fix this:

```
[ -x "$files" ] && printf "    %s\n" "$b"
```

While we’re at it, let’s fix the quoting:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
IFS=:
for dir in $PATH;do
        printf "%s:\n" "$dir"
        for files in "$dir"/*;do
                b="$(basename "$files")"
                [ -x "$files" ] && printf "    %s\n" "$b"
        done
done
```

See [List all commands that a shell knows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94775/86440) for a more comprehensive solution, which deals with empty entries in `PATH`, malformed entries which contain globs, and directories.