# Find commands/function whose name matches a value

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I am looking for some command e.g. `match ls` which should match commands like `ls`, `alsa` `asls`,.. and return them. I preferably want it to cover both all commands and defined functions. Is there a builtin command/application to do this?

Obviously, I can create my own script for that. But, I am asking just in case anyone knows of existing command/script that does the same?

Comment: Possibly related: [What are commands to find shell keywords, built in functions and user defined functions?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63073/what-are-commands-to-find-shell-keywords-built-in-functions-and-user-defined-fu/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a utility in `bash` called `compgen`.

```
# List all Commands
compgen -c

# List all Commands starting with ls
compgen -c ls

# List all Commands that has 'ls' in it
compgen -c | grep ls
```

Answer (score 0):

for `$PATH`'d commands there is:

```
set -f;   IFS=: PATH=$PATH:
set +f -- $PATH"$PWD"
for d
do    cd   -- "$d" &&
      hash -- *"$command"*
done; hash; PATH=${PATH%:}
```