# How to list all internal commands of a shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there any way to list all the `internal commands` of a `shell`. I am using `bash shell`. if I type `echo` then bash has internal `echo` command  so internal echo command will be executed( Internal command has more precedence than external command ). Is there any way to list all the `internal` commands of a `shell`.

Comment: Enter `help` at an interactive prompt.

Comment: Related: [List all commands that a shell knows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94775/list-all-commands-that-a-shell-knows), [What are commands to find shell keywords, built in functions and user defined functions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63073/what-are-commands-to-find-shell-keywords-built-in-functions-and-user-defined-fu)

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for your valuable information.